# Менять активный класс при скролле на соответсвующий блок

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

Всем привет.

У меня в `header`-е есть `4` блока при клике которые спускаютсья в соответсвующий контейнер и становятсья активными.(`active`)

Ну как сделать что если к примеру `user` нажал на блок `second` поскролилсья к этому блоку автоматично потом если он еще поскроллил к следующему блоку(`third`) как тогда менять класс вот я не знаю помогите пожалуйста.

И если кто подскажет как можно тут следовать принципу  [**DRY**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) буду при много благодарен.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".first").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#first").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
  $(".second").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#second").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
   $(".third").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#third").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
  $(".fourth").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#fourth").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
  $(function() {
  $(".list").click(function() {
     // remove classes from all
     $(".list").removeClass("active");
     // add class to the one we clicked
     $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
})
```

```css
.nav {
  position:fixed;
  background:#fff;
  height:70px;
}

ul {
  
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  width:400px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  
}
li {
  cursor:pointer;
}
li.active {
  background:yellow;
}
#first {
  width:400px;
  margin-bottom:160px;
}
#second {
  width:400px;
  margin-bottom:160px;
}

#third {
  width:400px;
  margin-bottom:160px;
}

#fourth {
  width:400px;
  margin-bottom:160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="list first active">first</li>
      <li class="list second">second</li>
      <li class="list third">third</li>
      <li class="list fourth">fourth</li>
    </ul>
  
  
</div>

<div id="first">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet ullam corporis, laborum quam velit possimus voluptatum molestiae hic, tempora est ipsam suscipit dolor, corrupti nemo incidunt inventore molestias quasi expedita.</p>
 <div>
   <div id="second">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet ullam corporis, laborum quam velit possimus voluptatum molestiae hic, tempora est ipsam suscipit dolor, corrupti nemo incidunt inventore molestias quasi expedita.</p>
 <div>
   
   <div id="third">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet ullam corporis, laborum quam velit possimus voluptatum molestiae hic, tempora est ipsam suscipit dolor, corrupti nemo incidunt inventore molestias quasi expedita.</p>
 <div>
   
   <div id="fourth">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet ullam corporis, laborum quam velit possimus voluptatum molestiae hic, tempora est ipsam suscipit dolor, corrupti nemo incidunt inventore molestias quasi expedita.</p>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь кому нибудь поможет этот код

```js
$('nav a').on('click', function() {

    var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
        scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 28;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 500);

    return false;

})
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".first").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
  $(".second").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#news").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
   $(".third").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#products").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
  $(".fourth").click(() => $('html,body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top}, 
  'slow'));
  
  $(function() {
  $(".list").click(function() {
     // remove classes from all
     $(".list").removeClass("active");
     // add class to the one we clicked
     $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
})

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 100) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        $('.wrapper section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20) {
                $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    } else {

        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
    }

}).scroll();
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

header {
    background: transparent url('http://adventure.nationalgeographic.com/2008/11/ecotourism/lodge-jungle.jpg') 0 0;
    height: 100px;
}

h4 {
   font-weight: bold;
    
}

p {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

section {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 28px 0 0 0;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right; 0;
    top: 100px;
    background: green;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 0;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
}

nav a {
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2px; 4px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a.active {
    background: white;
    color: green
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>

<nav>
        
    <a class="first" href="#" data-scroll="top">TOP</a>
        
    <a class="second" href="#" data-scroll="news">NEWS</a>
        
    <a class="third" href="#" data-scroll="products">PRODUCTS</a>
        
    <a class="fourth" href="#" data-scroll="contact">CONTACT</a>
    
</nav>

<div class="wrapper">
        
    <section  id="top" data-anchor="top">
        
        <h4>TOP</h4>
        
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>
             
    </section>
    
    <section id="news" data-anchor="news">
        
        <h4>NEWS</h4>
        
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>
             
    </section>
    
    <section id="products" data-anchor="products">
        
        <h4>PRODUCTS</h4>
        
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>
             
    </section>
    
    <section id="contact" data-anchor="contact">
        
        <h4>CONTACT</h4>
        
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>
             
    </section>
    
</div>
```